# How can I disable the file:// protocol in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, url, protocol, uri

How to disable file:// protocol in firefox

I want the users not to browse the local files on the machine.

I already disabled SaveAs and OpenFile functions.

I want user not to browse the local files or open it if he know the full path.

Comment: Remember to disable Help, too. Sometimes Help opens backdoors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do this.

First the scenario of our problem is:

- We want client to use a PCs and they have access to firefox only
- No "my computer","cmd",...etc.
- We want them not to browse local files by Firefox , just browsing some sites.
- We want to block file:// protocol that cause browsing of local files.

My suggested solution:

1. Download **[r-kiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1659)** extension and modify it to run on firefox 3.5.*
2. Modify userPref.js to show the address bar in firefox
   ---- here we stop Save as,open file,remove extension,no viewsource,but users still browse the localfiles by typing file:///c:/ in url.
3. Modify dirListing.css in Firefox/chrome/classic.jar/skin/classic/(skin name)/dirListing

   ```
   body{
              ...
              background-image:url(chrome://global/skin/dirListing/forbidden.png)
       }
   table{
   ...
   display:none;
   }
   ```

Hide elements like P,H1 by using `visiblity:hidden`

You can use this image created by me to make it as body background:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image: link text]

Comment: Shouldn't "r-kisok" (in bold, in like "1." above) be **r-kiosk**?

Comment: So, the accepted solution is to change Firefox's internal stylesheets in order to hide the directory listing?

Answer (score 1):

University of Waterloo has [a page detailing a change to browser.js](http://www.eng.uwaterloo.ca/twiki/bin/view/Linux/FirefoxLockdown) to disable file, chrome, about, etc. protocols.

That was the first result on Google for "firefox disable file protocol," by the way -- probably would have been the first one if this question wasn't the first result.

Comment: I already  visited this site 

and the code provided by them is:

if (location.match(/^file:/) || 
    location.match(/^\//) || 
    location.match(/^chrome:/) ||
    location.match(/^resource:/) ||
    (!location.match(/^about:blank/) &&
    location.match(/^about:/))) {
    loadURI("about:blank");
    } 

I found in other sites that to put this code in BrowserLoadURI 
function which is not found in ff3.x

Comment: The page suggests a blacklist, I'd go for a whitelist instead. "http" and "https", and perhaps "ftp" ought to be enough.