# How can firefox 100.0 block local drives?

Tags: windows, firefox, blocking, local-storage

How can Firefox block access to the entirety of the local storage, such as "file:///C:/" "file:///C:/Windows/" and so on ?

Thanks in advance

Edit : I'll reformulate :

How can I disable access to the local drives from firefox with the help of an extension/regedit setting ?

Comment: It doesn't. By default you have access to your user's area only but that has nothing to do with one specific software, it's a system-wide setting.

Comment: One possible solution is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/30402/how-can-i-disable-the-file-protocol-in-firefox). You can also block the url with a policy like [this](https://support.mozilla.org/mk/questions/1353830). Have you tried the policy solution?

Comment: Thanks for your time and sorry for being stupid, but the Block site extension works as long as I'm not braindead (which I was) 

Thanks again and sorry